# Visual Studio 2013 CTP3.1 IOS Build error

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I just start dev VS2013 Cordova project. I've 2 laptop one install VS2013 CTP3.0 can remote build IOS working fine like a charm but another Laptop VS2013 CTP3.1 with the same project I alway got error below.

```
Error   3   Invalid build request: The build request for cordova version 4.1.2 is not supported by the iOS build server. The server is installed with cordova version 4.0.0.    D:\SVN\CordovaApp\MDAVSCLI  1   1   CordovaApp
```

My mac mini has installed Cordova 4.3. 
I'm trying to find the way to downgrade to CTP3.0 but it seem Microsoft remove the link. Please suggestion how to deal with this problem.
For build android there is no problem on both laptops.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution just reinstall npm by running command below on mac
sudo npm install -g vs-mda-remote --user=$USER